# Hadoop: TaskTracker and JobTracker don't start with start-dfs.sh

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to set up hadoop 0.22.0 on my laptop for learning purpose using this link

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

When I run the script start-dfs.sh this is the ouput

```
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-raunak-namenode-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-raunak-datanode-ubuntu.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/bin/../logs/hadoop-raunak-secondarynamenode-ubuntu.out
```

The output of `jps` is:

```
18106 Jps
17269 NameNode
17556 DataNode
17845 SecondaryNameNode
```

But I can't see the `TaskTracker` or `JobTracker` running. So, can anyone please tell me what could I be missing. I am a total newbie and don't know what information is required. So, please let me know.

Comment: Delete all logs and try again.  Post any exceptions you find in the logs as part of your question.

Comment: And shouldn't you be using start-all.sh?

Comment: @ChrisGerken: Firstly I did use start-all.sh but it showed me that the script is deprecated. By the way I am installing hadoop 0.22.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with Chris Gerken's comment, you're running the `start-dfs.sh` script, which only starts the HDFS services. You'll need to run `start-mapred.sh` if you want the map reduce services (job tracker and task trackers).

Also, the deprecated message from `start-all.sh` hints towards this:

```
echo "This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-mapred.sh"
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using the newer version of hadoop, you might find it a little different from the tutorial you mentioned. Now all the `conf/` files will be in `hadoop-installation/etc/hadoop` directory.

All the hadoop daemons will be in `sbin/` directory.

Also, when you run `sbin/start-all.sh` the script will say that this command is deprecated and will ask you to run `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh` in my case.

`start-dfs.sh` started the `namenode` on master and `data-nodes` on `slave` and `secondarynamenode` on `localhost`.

`start-yarn.sh` started two new processes namely `ResourceManager` and `NodeManager`. Therefore I guess that the `ResourceManager` is the `JobTracker` and `NodeManager` is the `TaskTracker` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

JobTracker and TaskTracker are 2 essential process involved in MapReduce execution in MRv1 (or Hadoop version 1). 
Both processes are now deprecated in MRv2 (or Hadoop version 2) and replaced by Resource Manager, Application Master and Node Manager Daemons.
If you will just use start-all.sh then it will start your following services .

```
7120 ResourceManager
6787 DataNode
6981 SecondaryNameNode
7573 Jps
6678 NameNode
7229 NodeManager
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the JobTracker web interface default is `http://localhost:50030/` and TaskTracker web interface default is `http://localhost:50060/`. May be it is not showing in JPS for some reason.